# what is the correct way to code incoming links for SEO?

Tags: css, seo

our site is giving out 'badges' to our authors.  they can post these on their personal blogs and they will serve as incoming links to our site.

We want to give out the best possible code for SEO without doing anything that would get us flagged.

i would like to know what you're thoughts are on the following snippet of code and if anyone has any DEFINITE advice on dos and donts with it.  Also, let me know if any of it is redundant or not worth it for SEO purposes.

i've kept the css inline since some of the writers would not have access to add link to external css

i've changed the real values, but title, alt etc would be descriptive keywords similar to our page titles etc (no overloading keywords or any of that)

```
<div id="writer" style="width:100px;height:50px;>
<h1><strong style="float:left;text-indent:-9999px;overflow:hidden;margin:0;padding:0;">articles on x,y,z</strong>
    <a href="http://www.site.com/link-to-author" title="site description">
        <img style="border:none" src="http://www.site.com/images/badge.png" alt="description of articles" title="View my published work on site.com"/>
    </a>
</h1></div>
```

thanks

Comment: You might want to post this here http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `H1` to enclose your "badge" is a really bad idea—not in so much as it'll negatively affect SEO for *your* site, but it will very likely ruin the accessibility (and thus SEO) of the author site. `H1`-`H6` are used to provide document structure by semantically delimiting document headings. Random use of heading tags can confuse screen readers and webcrawlers. There's not much you can do in terms of legitimate SEO aside from making correct use of semantic HTML markup.

**Edit:**

Something like this would be the safest bet:

```
<div id="writer-badge" style="width: 100px; height: 50px;">
    <strong>
        Articles on x,y,z
    </strong>
    <br />
    <a href="..." title="site description" rel="profile">
        <img style="border: none" src="..." alt="..."
            longdesc="http://site.com/badges-explained"
        />
    </a>
</div>
```

I put a line-break between the text and image to treat the text as sort of a badge title. If it's not meant to be displayed that way, then I would omit the `<strong>` tags altogether (there's no semantic value in encapsulating the text that way, and any styling could be done using the `DIV` or a weight-neutral `SPAN` element).

IMO there's really no reason for a achievement badge to have a heading of its own (it's really not even part of the document, just a flourish in the layout), but if you absolutely must, then `H6` would be more appropriate and safer to use than `H1`.

As far as keyword proximity, that is sorta venturing into the grey-hat area of SEO (similar to keyword stuffing), and I wouldn't know anything about that. I've yet to come across any reliable info on how Google or other search engines treat keyword placement. I think if you properly use tag attributes like `alt`, `title`, `longdesc`, `rel`, `rev`, etc. in images and links, you'll be alright.

Comment: thanks for your answer - can you let me know what way would you code it?  if we remove h1, is there any value in leaving the <strong> tag beside the image link? (is any additional weight given from keywords in close proximity?)

Comment: also, would changing it to <h3> (for example) and adding a document element after the h3 tag make it correct in terms of semantic markup?  (since it would be the heading for that text)

Comment: If you're going to add text to the badge, then a section heading might be justifiable, but I would go for the least significant heading level since the badge itself isn't likely to be part of the document proper.

Comment: thanks - everyone assumes its just linking an image to our site, but the point is that we have the ability to add in extra markup and not just the image, so we want to get the best SEO bang for that.  I think it sounds right on the h1 - so the solution is probably to change to h6 and add a text element to go with the heading so that the html structure will be correct.  after all, sites embed links in h1 and h2 elements and use image replacement the whole time internally - e.g. main logos or section headings.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any issue with this code except your `<h1>` tag.  I would probably change it to `<h2>` simply because pages are supposed to have only 1 `<h1>` tag per page.

You could also use an iFrame instead if you wanted.  That is what SO does but I know you will not get as much linky goodness.

Comment: good point on the h1 - probably h4 or lower is more appropriate